# gsapi_init_with_args' is made -100 with long and Asian language in filename

Tags: c#, ghostscript.net

I'm using this function to "compress" PDF files. If the filename has Asian language (Japanese and Vietnamese) **and** the number of characters in filename is longer 15, the error "'gsapi_init_with_args' is made -100" will appear.

Example:

- Input Filename: "こんにちは、私の名前は.pdf" or "Xin chào, tôi tên là. Xin chào, tôi tên là.pdf"
- Output Filename: "こんにち.p" or "Xin cháo, tôi tơn lá". They're without extension in filename, zero size and incorrect filename.
- Expected Filename: "こんにちは、私の名前は.pdf" or "Xin chào, tôi tên là. Xin chào, tôi tên là.pdf" with smaller size.

If the filename has Asian language (Japanese and Vietnamese) **and** the number of characters in filename is shorter 15, it's OK to use.

My environment:

- Windows 11 English US 64-bit (Locale in Settings is Japanese)
- Ghostscript version: 9.55.0 32-bit
- Ghostscript.NET v1.2.3 (latest)
  Please help me fix this. Thank you in advance.

```
try
            {
                string strFilePath = PDFFile.FullName;
                string strFileNameOnly = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(PDFFile.Name);               
                
                GhostscriptVersionInfo gvi = GhostscriptVersionInfo.GetLastInstalledVersion();
                string strFullnameOutput = Path.Combine(strOutput, strFileNameOnly) + ".pdf";
List<string> switches = new List<string>
                {
                    "-empty",
                    "-dQUIET",
                    "-dSAFER",
                    "-dBATCH",
                    "-dNOPAUSE",
                    "-dNOPROMPT",
                    "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite",
                    "-dCompatibilityLevel=2.0",
                    "-dPDFSETTINGS =/default", 
                    "-sOutputFile=" + strFullnameOutput,
                    //"-dPrinted=false",                    
                    "-c",
                    "-f",
                    strFilePath,
                };                

                using (GhostscriptProcessor gsProc = new GhostscriptProcessor())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        gsProc.StartProcessing(switches.ToArray(), null);
                        isDone = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        isDone = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                isDone = false;
            }
```

I've tried to change another computer but same result.

Comment: If you think you have found a bug you should open a bug report. Be aware that Ghostscript.NET is not Ghostscript, it is not developed, maintained or supported by the Ghostscript development team. You will need to be able to demonstrate a problem using the Ghostscript API or pre-built binary.

Comment: @KenS Thanks for your help. I have reported the issue on GitHub at this link https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET/issues/107. Hopefully, there will be a way to overcome it.